# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.formatPaymentDate is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I've created a calendar in Vue to track payments due. In payment.js, I have a function, calculatePayments(payment), that takes a payment record and determines what dates on the current calendar to show a payment. Inside this function is a call to a mixin function, formatPaymentDate(nextPmtDate). This function is in formats.js.

When initially creating the calendar in a component called CalendarGrid.vue, calculatePayments is called several times, which in turn calls formatPaymentDate. This works fine. CalendarGrid.vue has a sibling component, PaymentEntry.vue, in which a new payment record can be created. This component has a "Save" button which calls calculatePayments, which in turn calls formatPaymentDate. When the "Save" button is clicked, I get the following error message:

Error in v-on handler:

> "TypeError: this.formatPaymentDate is not a function"

In PaymentEntry.Vue, I have the following import statement:

```js
import { formats } from "../library/formats";
```

formats.js:

```js
export const formats = {
  methods: {
     ...
     numericDate(date) {
       return this.formatDate(date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
     },
     formatPaymentDate(date) {
       return this.numericDate(date);
     }
  }
}
```

The pertinent code from payments.js:

```js
calculatePayments: function (payment) {
  let nextPmtDate = moment(payment.next);
  payment.next = this.formatPaymentDate(nextPmtDate);
}
```

I tried moving the import {format} statement to payments.js. When I do, VSCode greys it out.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't using a proper mixin format in my library